# understanding the arange() function in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
print(np.arange(-2, 2, 0.5, int))
```

so we have -2  -1.5  -1.0  -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5

```
output: [-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

can someone explain the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you have is rounding of float (-1.5) to an integer(-1). Then arrange() continues addition to a new integer(-1+0.5), which results in float(0.5) again. The floats are not allowed, so it's rounded to 0. And so the cycle continues producing observed output.